# Find a basis of the vector space of all harmonic homogeneous $n$-variate complex polynomials of degree $d$

Tags: polynomials, vector-spaces, harmonic-functions, spherical-harmonics, homogeneous-spaces

Consider $U_n = \mathbb{C}[x_1,...,x_n]$ - the vector space of all complex polynomials over with $n$ variables $x_1,...,x_n$ ($n \ge 2$). A polynomial $h \in U_n$ is homogeneous of degree $d \in \mathbb{N}$ when $h(\lambda x_1, ..., \lambda x_n) = \lambda^d h(x_1, ..., x_n) \; \forall \lambda \in \mathbb{C}$. It's known that the set of all homogeneous polynomials of degree $d$ in $U_n$ is a subspace of $U_n$, now called $V_{n,d}$. We have $\dim V_{n,d} = \binom{n+d-1}{n-1}$.

A polynomial $h \in V_{n,d}$ is harmonic when its [Laplacian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator#Definition) $\Delta h = 0 \in V_{n,d-2}$. Then, the set of all harmonic polynomials in $V_{n,d}$ is a subspace of $V_{n,d}$, now called $H_{n,d}$.

To exclude some trivial cases, we only consider $n \ge 2$ and $d \ge 2$.

**Problem:** Given $n, d \in \mathbb{N}$, describe an algorithm to systemically find a basis of $H_{n,d} \subset V_{n,d} \subset U_n$.

So far, I only know the fact that $\dim H_{3,d} = 2d+1$ for all $d$. I assume there is a formula for $\dim H_{n,d}$ w.r.t $n,d$ (I guess it's $\binom{n+d-1}{n-1} - \binom{n+d-3}{n-1}$). Regardless, besides the trivial cases, I have not achieved any progress in this problem.

Comment: As I prove the dimension formula of $H_{n,d}$, I come up with an inefficient algorithm. Define $T: V_{n,d-2} \rightarrow V_{n,d}$ as follows: $T(h) = h\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2$. Consider the $V$'s as vector spaces with their respective canonical bases, we can define $T$ as a sparse $\binom{n+d-1}{n-1} \times \binom{n+d-3}{n-1}$ 0-1 matrix. Then, with a suitable diagonal integral matrix $D$, we calculate a basis of the null space of $T^\top D$. That's a desired basis for $H_{n,d}$.

Comment: On the other hand, inspired by some of the compact solutions for $n=2$ (2 polynomials $(x_1 \pm i x_2)^d$) and $d=2$ ($\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ polynomials $(x_i + ix_j)^2 (i < j)$ and $n-1$ polynomials $(x_i - ix_{i+1})^2)$, I come up with a compact solution for $n=3$: $2d+1$ polynomials $(x_1 + i \cos(\phi) x_2 + i \sin(\phi) x_3)^d$ with $\phi = k\frac{2\pi}{2d+1}$ ($k = 0, ..., 2d$).

Comment: Within the same line of arguments, I come up with another compact solution for $n=3$, $2d+1$ polynomials $(x_1+x_2\sqrt{-1-e^{2i\phi}}+e^{i\phi}x_3)^d$ with $\phi = k\frac{2\pi}{2d+1} \; (k = 0,...,2d)$. Notice that this compact solution can be generalized to $n > 3$ by using the following facts: $\deg_d \dim H_{n,d} = n-2$, Kronecker products of Vandermonde matrices of distinct variables are invertible, the compact solution has the form $(x_1+x_2\sqrt{-1-\sum_j e^{2i\phi_j}}+\sum_j e^{i\phi_j}x_{j+2})^d$ and $\phi_j = k\frac{2\pi}{2m_j+1}$ with suitable $m_j$ and suitable ranges for $k$.

Comment: See Chapter 5 in the excellent (and freely available) textbook [Harmonic Function Theory](https://www.axler.net/HFT.html) by Axler, Bourdon and Ramey.